# Excel VBA Find Function - Not working with formula cells

Tags: excel, vba

Unable to get FIND to work with a formula cell containing text and locate the result on a sheet within a range.

I have created a button that when clicked should look at a cell, take the data and then search for the result in a column on a different sheet using exact match.

D11 holds a formula that returns a vlookup text result
When i press the button i do the following

```
Sub Button3_Click()
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Auspost_Data")

    strSearch = Worksheets("Report_Tool").Range("D11")
    wb.ws.Range("D:D").Select
    Selection.Find(strSearch)

End Sub
```

I expect the find to take the text value and find the exact match within the column range.

Comment: [`Range.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find) has some additional parameters that you'll want to specify: *LookIn* and *LookAt*

Comment: Hi, i did try What:= LookIn:= and LookAt:=

Comment: If i say swapped strSearch to "MOORE PARK" as an example. it works fine. its something with how im setting up the string then referencing it later.

Comment: You want `What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole`.

Comment: strSearch = Worksheets("Report_Tool").Range("D11")
    wb.ws.Range("D:D").Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Select ---------------error: Object does not support this property or method

Comment: Instead of trying to `Select`,  use a new `Range` variable: `Dim foundRng as Range`, then `Set foundRng = wb.ws.Range("D:D").Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole`.

Comment: Then to test that the range was actually found, `If Not foundRng is Nothing Then...`.

Comment: if i simplify it to just '''     Dim strSearch As String
    
    strSearch = Worksheets("Report_Tool").Range("D11").Text
    Worksheets("Auspost_Data").Range("D:D").Find(strSearch).Select ''' it gets an object variable error. if i substitute strSearch for actual text "ABCD" it works. i used MSGBOX and the strSearch is grabbing the right text and outputting.

Comment: If you get that error, then the `Find` did not find anything. Add `MsgBox strSearch="ABCD"`. Does it return `True`?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Sub Button3_Click()

    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim fnd As Range

    Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Auspost_Data")

    strSearch = Worksheets("Report_Tool").Range("D11")
    Set fnd = ws.Range("D:D").Find(strSearch)

    MsgBox fnd.Address

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this...

```
Sub Button3_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsCriteria As Worksheet
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim rng As Range


    If SheetExists("Auspost_Data") Then
        Set ws = Worksheets("Auspost_Data")
    Else
        MsgBox "There is no Sheet called " & ws.Name & " in the ActiveWorkbook.", vbCritical, "Sheet Not Found!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If SheetExists("Report_Tool") Then
        strSearch = Worksheets("Report_Tool").Range("D11")
    Else
        MsgBox "There is no Sheet called Report_Tool in the ActiveWorkbook.", vbCritical, "Sheet Not Found!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If strSearch = "" Then
        MsgBox "Search string is empty, there is nothing to find.", vbExclamation, "Empty Search String!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set rng = ws.Range("D:D").Find(what:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The search string " & strSearch & " is found in the cell " & rng.Address(0, 0) & ".", vbInformation, strSearch & " Found!"
    Else
        MsgBox "The search string " & strSearch & " was not found.", vbExclamation, strSearch & " Found!"
    End If

End Sub


Function SheetExists(shName As String) As Boolean
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sh = Worksheets(shName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not sh Is Nothing Then SheetExists = True
End Function
```

**To select the range if it is found:**

Replace the last IF statement with this...

```
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    ws.Select
    rng.Select
Else
    MsgBox "The search string " & strSearch & " was not found.", vbExclamation, strSearch & " Found!"
End If
```

Notice that I have removed the MsgBox if the rng is found which I think is not needed here specially when the code selects the rng found.

Comment: this is a great piece of code. issue still remains. example the cell D11 holds a formula VLOOKUP bla bla. the result is "MOORE PARK". now the code you provided when i press the button, says the search string was not found. but if i look at the data sheet in column d, i can see it there.

Comment: Working !!! had to TRIM() the VLOOKUP. looking closely at the msgbox prompt. it had spaces at the end of the string

Comment: Last part which still doesnt work is how would i go rng.Select to actually goto that cell.

Comment: rng.select and ws.Range("D:D").Find(what:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).select doesnt work.

Comment: noticed in the msgbox after the ".' there is no displayed text for , vbInformation, strSearch & " Found!"

Comment: As far as displayed text in `MsgBox` is concerned, if the search string is `MOORE PARK`, the `MsgBox` will display a msg like `The search string MOORE PARK is found in the cell <the cell address where the string was found.>`.

Comment: And as far as to select the rng if found is concerned, it will produce an error if you are not on the `Auspost_Data` Sheet. I have edited the code to select the rng if it is found.